# asp.net mvc 4 (razor) form submit not working

Tags: forms, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a form using Ajax.BeginForm but when i hit the submit button nothing happens. I look in the network tab in the debugger toolbar and no request is fired and there is no error in the javascript console. I am using jquery unobtrusive validation.

Here is my partial view code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateUser", "Account", new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "Post", 
            UpdateTargetId = "divCreateUser", 
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
            OnSuccess = "CreateUserFormOnSuccess(response)"
        }))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </li>
            </ol>
            @*Html.Captcha("Inceacra alta imagine", "Introduceti textul pe care il vedeti in imagine:", 5, "Obligatoriu")*@
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="$('#divCreateUser').modal('hide')">Anuleaza</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Salveaza" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
        }
```

Here are my actions:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //[CaptchaVerify("Captcha introdus nu este valid")]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {

                string token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, null, true);

                _emailRepository.SendConfirmationEmail(model.UserName, Url.Action("Confirm", new { id = token }));

                return Json(new { result = true });
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

And here is the model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your referencing `divCreateUser` in several places but i'm not seeing that markup anywhere?

Comment: divCreateUser is a wrapper for my form. I did not include it in the code because it broke code formatting and i could not submit the question

Comment: is it just this form that is broken or all forms?

Comment: Just this form. In this application this is the first modal window with form that i created

Comment: I would think that it would work better if the form tags were in the model div.